Why does only the Septuagint have "Cainan" in the genealogy in Genesis 10 and 11?
Who is Cainan, or, where was he invented?

The Septuagint records someone named Cainan between Arpachshad and Shelach in both Genesis 10:24 and 11:13. The Torah that we have today in Lashon Hakodesh does not record this name (nor anyone else between these two ancestors).
Common sense would say that it is much more likely that he was dropped than that he was added.  The difference is too big to be a typo, and this would be a very bizarre thing to deliberately add.  If the name got dropped, then people would be confused as to which version was right, whereas if it got added then all of the corrupted versions would have to agree with each other which would make it much harder for it to be accepted.
Judaism also believes that the Septuagint version of the Torah is inspired, or at least was when it was first written.  It’s also worth noting that Cainan is included in the Gospel of Luke which is believed to have been written between 80-90 CE.
It’s also worth mentioning that the years in the Tanach tend to add up to round numbers for important events in the history of Israel, and the years in the Septuagint are completely different.
Did people find it offensive to be descended from someone whose name sounded so close to Canaan?
If the Hebrew text is correct, then where did this Cainan figure come from and how did this version become so widespread?

Did people find it offensive to be descended from someone whose name sounded so close to Canaan? This sounds very far fetched. Even a cursory glance at Torah or Talmud would leave one with a strong impression that Hashem and the Rabbis are not afraid to admit our shortcomings, nationally (to say the least)

The question should be migrated to Biblical Hermeneutics, as the scope of it is definitely against the dogma of the adherents here, as it is beyond the level of Rabbinic Judaism.

Bearing in mind that not a single other name is repeated in the generations between Adam-Noah and Noah-Abraham, then it may well be the other way around: someone confused Adam with Noah, and so took the name of the fourth generation from Adam (Cainan) and inserted it as the fourth generation from Noah.

Considering the modern Septuagint is a Christian invention and completely unrelated to the Jewish historical Septuagint, I'm not sure why this question is in the Judaism SE.

The later Xian LXX versions was a later modified version that harmonised with their current Heb version etc. But scholars identify the oldest LXX, see NETS LXX. The Brenton LXX English is also accurate and critical. @meir it would not explain why Jubilee has the same. It's just diff versions of stories explaining the evil genesis of Canaanites for being cursed.

@Michael16 Sure it would. Depending which came first, Jubilees or the version of the Septuagint with this insertion, the mistake was made in one and then propagated to the other.

The blotting out of the name of cursed Cainaan for a special hatred to astrology or black magic among the Mesorah is more likely than another transmission adding the name along with an elaborate story for it. I also read that somewhere perhaps Chronicles, the genealogy is written with 3 names, but only with Cainaan's reference, one is missing in the MT.

Andrew E. Steinmann, 'Challenging the Authenticity of Cainan, Son of Arpachshad', Journal of the Evangelical Theological Society 60 (2017), pp. 697-711, pointed out that when examining ancient sources, including various targums, Seder Olam, various Torah/Pentateuch traditions, the oldest manuscripts of Luke and the writings of the Church Fathers, it becomes clear that evidence for Cainan is only known from the 4th century CE and onwards, and even then the evidence is somewhat sporadic. He argued that "Cainan" was accidentally inserted into late 3rd or early 4th century versions of Luke as a scribal error, and from there permeated to the Septuagint and Jubilees. The Septuagint as we have it is a later work based on the efforts of the Church Fathers to create a standard Greek biblical translation,1 while the oldest manuscripts of Jubilees that are known to have Cainan are the Ethiopian Ge'ez manuscripts from the 15th century and onwards, and were likely translated from the Greek version, not the Hebrew original.2

1 For more information on the modern Septuagint, see what I've written here and here.
2 And see Steinmann's response to arguments against his paper here.

קינן/Keinan is recorded as the child of Enosh and father of Mahalalel in the Masoretic Text (Bereishis 5), with the Septuagint concurring.
As it relates to the Septuagint, R. Moshe David (Umberto) Cassuto (to 10:24) thinks that it was a later addition.
Here is his comment (to 10:24):

בתרגום השבעים: וארפכשד ילד את קינן, וקינן ילד את שלח, בהקבלה לתולדות בני שת שבפרק ה'. וכך מספר ס' היובלים על קינן בן ארפכשד. אבל כנראה אין זו אלא הוספה מאוחרת. ועי' להלן, על פס' ל"א.
In the Septuagint translation: "Arpachshad begat Cainan, and Cainan begat Shelah," paralleling the genealogy of the descendants of Seth in chapter 5. The Book of Jubilees also mentions Cainan, the son of Arpachshad. However, this is likely a later addition. See further below, on verse 31.


Also, the Samaritan Bible does not have the extra person.

Interesting.  Could you also add his comment on verse 31? Thank you.

@YDJ It isn't germane to the answer, so I left it out, but here it is: גם במבנה פיסקה זו חוזרים המספרים שבע ושתים עשרה. לפי נוסחת המסורה בניו ובני בניו של שם, עד פלג, הם שנים עשר. בשם יקטן, אחיו של פלג, מתחילה סדרה חדשה, הסדרה של השבטים הערביים, יקטן ושלושה עשר בניו: בין הכל ארבעה עשר, פעמיים שבעה. לפי נוסחת השבעים, המוסיפה את קינן בן ארפכשד לפני שלח, והמשמיטה את עובל מבין בני יקטן, המספרים הפוכים: ארבעה עשר בניו ובני בניו של שם עד יקטן ועד בכלל, ושנים עשר בני יקטן.

The LXX and Luke reading are ancient, not added after 1st century, as the LXX NETS critical edition shows. I searched the Google books with the keywords on this and found a helpful reference: Genesis A Commentary by Bruce Watke, (2001) p. 181 states,

Gen 11:12 When Arphaxad had lived 35 years, he became the father of Shelah. This should read, “When Arphaxad had lived 35 years, he became father of Cainan. And after he became the father of Cainan, Arphaxad lived 430 years and had others sons and daughters. When Cainan had lived 34 years he became the father of Shelah. And after he became the father of Shelah, Cainan lived 330 years and had other sons and daughters.” This reading is based on the Greek text and Luke 3:35-36 (see Gen. 10:24), From a text-critical point of view, it is much simpler to explain an accidental deletion of a name than an addition. This deletion is explained easily by the similarity of the two entries,12* a common scribal error. In all likelihood, the Masoretic text then was corrected as necessary to accommodate the omission. This seems more likely than a scribe adding a name to a  fixed genealogy. Some, supporting the Masoretic text, argue that Abraham is the tenth generation, but the parallel is imprecise, for they include the segmented genealogy as part of the linear, unlike the ten linear names in Genesis 5.
fn 12: LXX reads 130 years, but the additional 100 years is presumably the typical later correction of
that recension (see n. 9 above).
fn. 9: The textual recensions of the SP and of the LXX add one hundred years to the ages of the patriarchs from Arphaxad to Serug at the first son's birth. Perhaps they did so to distance Abraham from Shem and to assure that only Abraham's near ancestors were still alive when he was born. As a whole, the Masoretic text shows itself as more reliable than the other two smoothed recensions, but its omission of Cainan between Arphaad and Shelah is probably secondary. See Waltke, “Samaritan Pentateuch,” 212-39; and G. Larsson, “The Chronology of the Pentateuch: A Comparison of the MT and LXX.” JBL 102 (1983): 401-9.

I found the actual answer through the reference found in The Book of Genesis
Composition, Reception, and Interpretation 2012, fn, p. 398.

Samaritan Hebrew texts of Genesis. See Helen R. Jacobus, “The Curse of Cainan (Jub. 8:1-5): ‘Genealogies in Genesis 5 and Genesis 11 and a Mathematical Pattern.” JSP 18 (2009): 207-232.

Helen writes that Cainan was cursed for obtaining forbidden knowledge of the Watchers.

Cainan, the father of Shelach, son of Arpachshad, grandson of Shem and great-grandson of Noah, is listed in the genealogies of Shem in the Septuagint (LXX), LXX Gen. 10.24, Gen. 11.12-13; ( LXX A) 1 Chron. 1.18; and Lk. 3.36-37 as the thirteenth generation from Adam.
He is conspicuously absent from the Masoretic text (MT) and the Samartian Pentateuch (SP) where it is stated that Arpachshad, the ﬁrst patriarch to be born after the Flood (Gen. 10.1), is the father of Shelach (MT, SP Gen. 10.24; Gen. 11.12-13; 1 Chron. 1.18, 24) instead of Cainan
An explanation for this discrepancy between the LXX and the Masoretic and Samartian versions of the Pentateuch is contained in a surprisingly elaborate narrative in Jub. 8.1-5. According to Jubilees, Cainan, the thirteenth generation from Adam, was sent away after he
discovered the secrets of astronomy and astrology. This knowledge had been imparted by the fallen angels, the Watchers, to human beings before the Flood and these terrestrial ancestors had carved the secrets into rock.

This is why his name has been blotted out by the certain textual transmission. It also seems that Canaan of Gen 9:18-29 is perhaps the same Cainan from a different source as he has been cursed for his father Ham's sin of not covering up his father Noah, in that version.

I didn't downvote, but Jacobus's theory sounds too wildly conspiratorial. Is there really any sin that's too horrible that it's to be erased from the Torah? Sounds atypical of the Torah.

@Harel13 there is one consequece. If Keinan and Canaan are the same then it explains why Canaanim were Semitic people. Calling them bnei Ham implies that they should not live in Eretz Israel. Very much like Pelishtim vs. Bnei Dan.

However, the description regarding astrology is more fitting for pre-flood generations who had fallen angels etc.

@YDJ I don't understand the nafka mina. Canaanites are considered Semitic per the scholarly definition, which is simply by the language they used, which is part a group called the Semitic languages. Yes, the term is biblical, but doesn't refer to genealogy in this context. Other than that, we know ethnic groups migrated all over. And what do the Plishtim and Dan have to do with this?

I don't think it's Helen's theory alone, but must be common sense well known fact. Plz study scholarly books on Torah textual criticism etc, the DSS & LXX often corrects the MT, as we see in footnotes of Xian bibles. MT is 10th century AD, whereas DSS LXX are before Christ. @YDJ if Cainan astrology was pre flood it would've destroyed permanently. It should be after flood. Diff sources can say diff versions. Cain the 1st murderer is the same by another version. All versions collected in 1 book. You can tie any current enemies as sons of Cainan or Canaan or Cain

Readers are encouraged to up vote my answers to cancel the hate false votes due to insecurity and hatred to God.

What's common sense about this? And have you not considered the possibility that whoever downvoted simply thinks your explanation is wrong? I myself don't like downvoting, but as you can see, I don't like your explanation. It has absolutely nothing to do with insecurity or hatred for God, God-forbid.

I understand that, and this dislike is same as hatred. If people start censoring and putting down every truth or Holy teaching they will ban all teachers and create a new idolatry of mob rule for themselves. Mere dislike of answers is not a justification for downvotes. We should be tolerant to do verse views. My answers are highly informative. The opponents should consider the possibility of their insecurity and intolerance to things that go against their dogma. 3 or more downvotes disappear an answer.

In what world is "dislike" the same as "hatred"? And you never responded to my first question: What's common sense about this explanation? That some academics have a tendency to see conspiratorial scribal censorship around every corner doesn't make it common sense.
